# Null Value Exception On Property That Is Not Null

Tags: c#, xaml

Getting a NullValueException on a Property that Isn't null

Here's the code for the beginnings of a ViewModel, and the method that creates the ViewModel object and opens the Window I am using the ViewModelt in.  The exception is being thrown on the SwitchName property.  The _ciscoswitch.SwitchName is coming up as null because the _ciscoswitch in the SwitchVewModel is null.   The exception is getting thrown at InitializeComponent() in the SwitchBrowser constructor.  Looking at the SwitchVewModel instance in the debugger, _ciscoswitch is not null.   I tried changing the SwitchName accessor to use CiscoSwitch.switchName instead of _ciscoswitch.SwitchName, it still failed.

```
class SwitchViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
      #region Construction
    /// Constructs the default instance of a SwitchViewModel
    public SwitchViewModel()
    {

    }


    public SwitchViewModel(CiscoSwitch cs)
    {
       _ciscoswitch = cs;
    }
      #endregion
    #region Members

    CiscoSwitch _ciscoswitch;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public CiscoSwitch CiscoSwitch
    {
        get
        {
            return _ciscoswitch;
        }
        set
        {
            _ciscoswitch = value;
        }
    }

    public string SwitchName
    {
        get { return _ciscoswitch.switchName; }
        set
        {
            if (_ciscoswitch.switchName != value)
            {
               _ciscoswitch.switchName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("switchName");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        // take a copy to prevent thread issues
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
}
```

XAML for the SwitchBrowserWindow  the only property I am using right now is the SwitchName to try and get this working

```
<Window x:Class="CiscoDecodeWPF.SwitchBrowser"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:CiscoDecodeWPF="clr-namespace:CiscoDecodeWPF" IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}"
    Title="SwitchBrowser" Height="500" Width="500" Background="GhostWhite">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" x:Key="ModuleStyle">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" x:Key="RedModuleStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ModuleStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.DataContext>
    <CiscoDecodeWPF:SwitchViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid Margin="0,0,-211.4,-168">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="StackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,188.6,114">

        <StackPanel.Resources> 
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" x:Key="LabelStyle">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Label Content="Switch Name:" Name="Label1" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Label Content="Software Version:" Name="Label2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <Label Content="Model Number:" Name="Label3" HorizontalAlignment="left"/>
        <Label Content="IP Address:" Name="Label4" HorizontalAlignment="left"></Label>
        <Label Content="Serial Number:" Name="Label5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Label>
        <Label Content="Show Tech Taken:" Name="Label6" HorizontalAlignment="left"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Margin="105,0,218,489">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" x:Key="LabelStyle">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=SwitchName}" Name="SwitchNameLabel" HorizontalAlignment="left"/>
        <Label Content="Version" Name="VersionLabel" HorizontalAlignment="left"/>
        <Label Content="Model" Name="ModelNumberLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Label Content="IP" Name="IPAddressLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Label Content="Serial" Name="SerialLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Label Content="ST" Name="ShowTechLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

    </StackPanel>
```

Exception, stack trace and call stack

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
 Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=CiscoDecodeWPF
StackTrace:
   at CiscoDecodeWPF.SwitchViewModel.get_SwitchName() in 

d:\Projects\CiscoDecodeWPF\CiscoDecodeWPF\SwitchViewModel.cs:line 50
```

InnerException:

> CiscoDecodeWPF.exe!CiscoDecodeWPF.SwitchViewModel.SwitchName.get() Line 50 + 0xf bytes  C#
>       [External Code] 
>       CiscoDecodeWPF.exe!CiscoDecodeWPF.SwitchBrowser.SwitchBrowser(CiscoDecodeWPF.CiscoSwitch cs) Line 35 + 0x8 bytes    C#
>       CiscoDecodeWPF.exe!CiscoDecodeWPF.MainWindow.BrowseSwitchMenuItem_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) Line 1050 + 0x34 bytes C#
>       [External Code]

Comment: It is almost certainly something wrong in your XAML. Please post that (and remove some of the C#)

Comment: Also, post the entire stack trace.

Comment: With the `FirstOrDefault` in `new SwitchBrowser(cs.FirstOrDefault())` you can easily pass in a `null` as `CiscoSwitch`...  and if your code uses the default `public SwitchViewModel()` constructor `_ciscoswitch` will be also `null`...

Comment: @ChrisF, posted the XAML for the SwitchBrowserWindow, or at least up to the bit that uses the SwitchName

Comment: @Kirk, posted the Exeption and what the debugger gives for the stack trace

Comment: I am wondering if Initialize() on the SwitchBrowserWindow is using the default constructor for the ViewModel - that would explain this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code in `SwitchName`:

```
 public string SwitchName
{
    get {
         if (_ciscoswitch != null)
         {   
           return _ciscoswitch.switchName;
         }
         else
         {
            return string.empty;
         }
      }
    set
    {
      if (_ciscoswitch != null)
      {
        if (_ciscoswitch.switchName != value)
        {
           _ciscoswitch.switchName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("switchName");
        }
      }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to check `_ciscoswitch  != null` in `SwitchName` then put `DataContext = svm` before InitizlizeComponent()

**CODE:**

```
public SwitchBrowser(CiscoSwitch cs)
{
    SwitchViewModel svm = new SwitchViewModel(cs);
    DataContext = svm;
    InitializeComponent();
 }
```

And remove below code from `XAML`.

```
<Window.DataContext>
<CiscoDecodeWPF:SwitchViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Hope It should Work.

Comment: thanks Jignesh, the _ciscoswitch isn't supposed to be null.  I have an instance of the CiscoSwitch object I am trying to pass in as the model.

Comment: @DavidGreen <Label Content="{Binding Path=SwitchName}" Name="SwitchNameLabel" HorizontalAlignment="left"/> this line trying to get Switchname from viewmodel but at that time _ciscoswitch is null.

Comment: With CiscoSwitch parameter New() of ViewModel, you are creating it at codebehind and you assigned DataContext value after Initialization(). But at design time you just created New object of Viewmodel with default New(). Just try with my answer.

Comment: that worked. the problem is there are several properties and apparently I will have to test them all.  I'd rather find a way to have the XAML call the constructor that takes a paramter, if there is a way.  I haven't been able to find one so far.

Comment: @DavidGreen see my updated answer, before InitializeComponent() assign DataContext value.

Comment: that didn't work either.  the SwitchView object Initialize() was calling the default constructor for the SwitchViewModel.  I added a line to the default constructor on SwitchViewModel to create a new switch.  That lets initialize finish, then I set DataContext to the actual SwitchViewModel with data in it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17621/discussion-between-david-green-and-jignesh-thakker)